# How to remove an element AFTER animation completes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm using the following code to animate a div.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("a.shift").click(function() {
      $("#introOverlay").animate({
        height: 0,
      }, 2000)
    });
  });
</script>
```

When the animation finishes, I would like to remove it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[animate](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate) takes 2 more params, so you could do:

```
$("a.shift")
    .click(function() 
        {
            $("#introOverlay")
                .animate({height: 0}, 2000,"linear",function()
                    {
                        $(this).remove();
                    }
                )
        }
    );
```

Untested.

EDIT: Tested: here's the full page I used, which expands to 300px make removal more obvious:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $(".shift").click(function() 
                {
                    $("#introOverlay")
                    .animate({height: 300}, 2000,"linear",function()
                    {
                        $(this).remove();
                    })
                });
            });
            //]]>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a class="shift" href="javascript:void(0)">clickme</a>
    <div id="introOverlay" style="background-color:red;height:200px;">overlay</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Spender,
That doesn't remove the element when animation has finished.

Answer (score 4):

Put the `remove()` call in the effects queue like this:

```
$("a.shift").click(function() {
  $("#introOverlay").animate({
    height: 0,
  }, 2000);
  $("#introOverlay").queue(function() {
    $(this).remove();
    $(this).dequeue();
  });
});
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to update text in the queue. This words great to put non-queue calls like .text("") into the queue.

Answer (score 3):

[JQuery animate(params, [duration], [easing], [callback] )](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate)  offers the possibility to add a callback that is called for every time the animation is completed

> callback (Optional)   Function:    A
>   function to be executed whenever the
>   animation completes, executes once for
>   each element animated against.

The syntax is pretty much jQuery straightforward:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("a.shift").click(function() {
        $("#introOverlay").animate({
        height: 0,
        }, 2000, "linear",
            function() {
                $("#introOverlay").hide();
            }
        )
        });

    })
</script>
```

See also this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078969/how-can-i-make-a-function-wait-until-an-animation-completes/1078995#1078995)

Comment: Thanks Daff,
Can you give me some sample code?  It's the syntax I don't understand.

Comment: Check out the question I linked, there is a code sample there (copied it here, too). Basically you just pass the callback function as a parameter.

Answer (score -2):

Use window.timeout with the same amount of time as taken by the animation.