# How to remove a element after animation?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I don't much css animations. I want to remove an element after animation. So I'm using [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css). I have tried below code but it still not working.

```
function deleteDevice(id) {
    $('#'+id).addClass("animated bounceOutRight");
    $('#'+id).queue(function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $(this).dequeue();
   });
}
```

How to remove the element after the animation?

Comment: check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432548/how-to-remove-an-element-after-animation-completes

Comment: I'm not using any animate function. I'm simply using others css file. @MohitBhasi

Comment: read about call back function it will help you lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect when animation done with this. Read [here](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css#usage)

```
$('#yourElement').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', doSomething);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    deleteDevice('element');
  });
});


function deleteDevice(id) {
  $('#' + id).addClass("animated bounceOutRight");

  $('#element').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
}
```

```css
@import url(http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/animate.min.css
);
 div {
  background: #abcdef;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Delete</button>
<div id="element"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a callback function which will be fired when your animation ends, at that moment you can remove/hide your HTML.

In the following code I am removing the animated div from the DOM, you could potentially just hide it.

http://jsfiddle.net/yhwebLon/2/

```
<button>Start Animation</button>

<div id="target" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>




$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#target").animate({left: '250px'}, function(){
            alert('animation done');
            $("#target").remove();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: My animation will bounce and move left. And I'm not familiar with css animations. And I would like to use "animate.css". So is there any other posibility?